# Valuations and logic

Tags: predicate-logic

I have been given the question Let $$Var=\{x,y,z\}$$ $$ U=\{0,1,2\}$$ $$I(p)=\{(0,1),(1,2)\}$$

Give a valuation so that P(x,y) is true?

What is a valuation? I do not understand it intuitively.

Also what does I(p) mean?

Comment: $I(P)$ means (probably) the interpretation of the (binary) *predicate* letter $P$ and thus it is a (binary) relation; in your case : $I(P) = \{ (0,1), (1,2) \}$. A *valuation* is a function $s: Var \to U$ that assign a "temporary" denotation to the variables.

Comment: So to interpretation of a predicate symbol is I(P) and an interpretation of a function symbol is I(F)?

Comment: In order to show the curly brackets, you have to write : \{ and not simply : { ...

Comment: Yes; in general, an *interpretation* assign a "meaning" to the symbols of the language: for a *constant* $c$, $I(c)$ is an element of the domain $D$; for a $n$-ary *predicate* symbol $P$ is an $n$-ary *relation* $I(P)$ on the domain; for a $n$-ary *function* symbol $f$ is a mapping $I(f) : D^n \to D$.

Comment: SO for the above question, what would an valuation be so that p(x,y) is true? Would it just be v(x)=0 and v(y)=1?

Comment: Why would we want to assign a temporary" denotation to the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a first-order language $\mathcal L$ and an *interpretation* $I$ on a *domain* (or *universe*) $U$ of elements, the *valuation* (or *variable assignment*) function :

> $s : Var \to U$

assigns a "temporary" denotation to the *variables*.

If we consider the domain $U = \{ 0,1,2 \}$ and a (binary) *predicate* $P$ such that $I(P) = \{ (0,1),(1,2) \}$, in order to evaluate the truth value of the atomic formula $P(x,y)$, we have to define a valuation $s$.

With an $s$ such that :

> $s(x)=0$ and $s(y)=1$,

the formula $P(x,y)$ has now a truth value; this value is "calculated" using the elements of the domain that are the "temporary" denotation of the variables $x,y$ occurring free in the formula.

In our case, we have that $P(x,y)[s]$ is $P(0,1)$, that is *true* because $(0,1) \in I(P)$.

We write also :

$I,s \vDash P(x,y)$

meaning that the formula $P(x,y)$ is *satisfied* by the *interpretation* $I$ with the *valuation* $s$.

---

A slightly more "real" example is obtained for the language of first-order *arithmetic*.

Let $U$ be the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers with the "usual" *interpretation* for the (binary) *predicate* $<$, the (unary) function $S$ ("successor"), the (binary) *functions* $+$ ("sum") and $\times$ ("product") and the (individual) *constant* $0$ ("zero").

What is the truth value in this interpretation of the formula :

> $x > 0$ ?

If we introduce a *valuation* $s$ that assign as denotation to the variable $x$ the element $0$ of the domain (i.e. $s(x)=0$), we obtain :

> $(x > 0)[s]$ i.e. $0 > 0$, that is *false*,

while if we use an $s'$ such that $s'(x)=1$, we obtain :

> $(x > 0)[s']$ i.e. $1 > 0$, that is *true*.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help today :)